# wxpython RichTextCtrl. How to set a background color to a text selection

Tags: wxpython

for example this is for bold Weight:

```
rtc.ApplyBoldToSelection()
```

I'm trying the feature highlight word in an editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a convient method for that, but doing a bit of searching in the wxPython demo for RichTextCtrl I came up with the following.

```
attr = wx.TextAttr()
attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_TEXT_COLOUR)
r = rtc.GetSelectionRange()
attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_TEXT_COLOUR)
attr.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
rtc.SetStyle(r, attr)
```

You would probably want to put that into a method you can then reuse.

Comment: this works great for me. only a small tuning. wx.richtext.TextAttrEx instead of: wx.richtext. Thanks Werner!

Answer (score -2):

Setting background color for `wx.richtext` during initial writing.

```
import wx.richtext as rt  
self.rtc.WriteText("This is BLUE background with WHITE text, This is RED background with BLACK text")  
self.rtc.SetStyle( (0,41), rt.RichTextAttr(wx.TextAttr("WHITE", "BLUE")) )  
self.rtc.SetStyle( (42,79), rt.RichTextAttr(wx.TextAttr("BLACK", "RED")) )
```